# iOS: Using @min and @max in a core data predicate

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data entity, `Client`, which has a `discount`property. I want to fetch the the client with the smallest discount.

I am using the following `NSPredicate`:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"@min.discount"];
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "@min.discount"'
```

What am not doing right?

Comment: What are you looking is this: [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide: Collection Operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think `NSPredicate` has support for functions like this unless it is part of a boolean predicate expression (i.e. involving things like "greater than").

You should read [this CoreData documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6) which gives some examples, specifically using `max` as an example:

> There are a number of steps to follow to create and use the expression
>   description.
>
> First you need to create expressions (instances of `NSExpression`) to represent the key-path for the value you’re interested in, and to
>   represent the function you want to apply (such as max: or min:):
>
> ```
> NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"salary"];
> NSExpression *maxSalaryExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:"
>                                                   arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
> ```
>
> For a full list of supported functions, see `expressionForFunction:arguments:`.
>
> You then create the expression description and set its name, expression, and result type.
>
> The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value. If you want to retrieve multiple values—such as the
>   largest and the smallest salaries in an Employee table—the name of
>   each expression description must be unique for a given fetch request.
>
> ```
> NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
> [expressionDescription setName:@"maxSalary"];
> [expressionDescription setExpression:maxSalaryExpression];
> [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];
> ```
>
> Finally, you set the request’s properties to fetch just the property represented by the expression:
>
> ```
> [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
> ```